# C# - How to create a CSR with a template, forwarding it to an intermediate server which enrolls the cert from PKI and get back a PKCS#7 in response

Tags: c#, x509certificate, pki, csr

I have situation where I have to decouple my edge server with the PKI server. The edge server requires a signed certificate to be installed in it. With current proposed approach, I need to create a CSR with a template received from the PKI policies, forward the csr to the intermediate server which gets the CSR signed and get a PKCS#7 in response from the PKI and then it returns back the PKCS#7 cert to the edge where it bundles with its private key generated in the first step and generated PKC#12, which gets stored in the local machine store for further use. Its a C# code and I'm using X509 certs.

1st method ----------

```
public static Pkcs10CertificationRequest CreateNReturnCSR(string name)
  {
        var keyGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyGenerator.Init(
            new KeyGenerationParameters(
                new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()),
                2048));
        var keyPair = keyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
        X509Name name2 = new X509Name("CN=" + name);
        Pkcs10CertificationRequest csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest("SHA256WITHRSA", name2, keyPair.Public, null, keyPair.Private);
```

//Where to mention template here?

```
        return csr;
```

}

2nd method------------ 
UseCSRNReturnCert(csr) -- Not implemented

3rd method -----------
BundleNInstallCert() -- Not implemented

Comment: hi, welcome to SO, so what's the problem?

Comment: The issue is, I need to generate CSR in one server, send it to the 2nd server where it will get it signed from a 3rd PKI server and return back the PKCS7 to 1st server to get bundled with private key and generate PKCS12

Comment: ok, so what have you done so far, and what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Just started working on it. Have created 3 methods as of now CreateNReturnCSR(), UseCSRNReturnCert(), BundleNInstallCert() where 1st n 3rd will be used in the 1st server and the 2nd in the intermediate server. In the 1st method, i have to create a csr with a template, and the key pair generated. Currently Im stuck there.

Comment: var keyGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            keyGenerator.Init(
                new KeyGenerationParameters(
                    new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()),
                    2048));
            var keyPair = keyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            X509Name name2 = new X509Name("CN=" + name);
            Pkcs10CertificationRequest csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest("SHA256WITHRSA", name2, keyPair.Public, null, keyPair.Private); ------- where to put the IX509CertificateTemplate object here?

Comment: **Edit your code into your question.**

Comment: Done Sir. Have edited.

Comment: If you are looking to generate CSR and Download Certificate from web application, please refer stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885